# Android-Youtube API won't load when I pass videoID with intent

Tags: java, android, string, youtube-api

I display a listView of video and When I click to an video Item I want to load it.So 
I pass the video ID by :

```
intent.putExtra("videoId",mAdapter.vidoeList.get(position).getId());
```

And there is My PlayerActivity code :

```
public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private YouTubePlayerView player;
String link;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    player=(YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
    this.link = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoId");
    player.initialize("MY_API", this);

}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    Log.v("MY_TAG:",link);

    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(link);
    youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);

}
```

When I look to log verbose I get the link but the Video won't load I get this error : 
**there was a problem with network [400]
Tap to try**

[image]

But when I use  youTubePlayer.loadVideo("ID_VIDEO") it load

Could you help me...
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check is your ID correct?

Comment: yes I did more then once

Comment: If you check and your `link` contains correct ID try to replace Intent code with: `Intent intent = getIntent();`  `link = intent.getStringExtra("videoId");`

Comment: That error usually comes if you are passing whole url of video

Comment: When I use  youTubePlayer.loadVideo("0GoGcVs6pbU"); or link=" 0GoGcVs6pbU"; youTubePlayer.loadVideo(link);It is work but when use
Intent intent = getIntent(); link = intent.getStringExtra("videoId"); youTubePlayer.loadVideo(link); it won't

Comment: What is your Log.v() inside  says about link, put a break point and see did you get correct value for link

Comment: I get the correct Id, I am going to lose my mind with that

Comment: Finally,I solve it,It was my fault ... I put space at the end of the ID string
thanks for your help